# Chemical analysis of campholene nitrile

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, nitriles

I have a problem. I am synthesizing an organic compound called campholene nitrile (2,2,3-trimethylcyclopent-3-en-1-ylacetonitrile).

[image]

I need to analyze it. But there's a problem. I do not work for a university or company, so I do not have access to many of the modern analytical methods. I do have access to:

- Boiling point (it's a liquid)
- Basic chemical tests

So you see, I don't have that much at my disposal. In case it helps, I'm synthesizing it by the isomerization of camphor oxime with 30% sulfuric acid.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could do this analysis using my resources and be reasonably sure of its identity?

Comment: It very much depends on what are your purity requisites. If you just need to know if the reaction went well, just follow the literature including the isolation step (likely distillation, if you have that setup). Explain what "I have to analyse it" means. If that is true, likely you have to contact an university service or a private lab.

Comment: Can you get TLC plates?